# How do I release the assets of a page after I leave the page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I have a windows 8.1 universal c# app that syncs with Amazon S3 to see if there is updated content (images and video).

If there is updated content, the user can click the "update" button and this navigates the user to an updating page where the update takes place.

The way the update works is it downloads all of the new assets to a new directory. Once this is done, it copies over the "unchanged" files from the old directory into this new directory. Finally, the app deletes the old directory and renames the new directory to the old name.

The problem is that the app is still "using" the assets in the old directory and I need to know how to "release" these resources so I can rename and delete the old directory.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: This will be up the application reading the file in question. There need to be some reload trigger that forces the file descriptor to be closed, do your replacement, and then reopen the file descriptor.